# How to get last two words written in Regex in Javascript

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I am trying to get data after a colon.

This is my code:

```
function myFunction() {

  var withBreaks = "*Cats are:* cool Pets [CATS]"
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  if (withBreaks) {
    var tmp;
    tmp = withBreaks.match(/^[\*]Cats are:[\*][\s]([a-z]+[\s]+[A-Za-z].*)$/m); //
      var username = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No username';
  sheet.appendRow([username])
}
};
```

So I'm trying to get information after the 
`*Cats are:*`. This code works, but, sometimes some sentences would have an asterisk and sometimes there wouldn't be an asterisk to different sentences. I would like to make one that is more unifying, if that clarifies my question a bit.

What I would like to do is, without specifying the asterisk, get data after the :. So anything after Cats are:. Do I have to specify the asterisk?

Comment: If you need to get all after `*Cats are:*`, use `/^\*Cats are:\*\s*([\s\S]*)/`

Comment: Do I have to specify the asterisks? Is there a way that goes around specifying the asterisks?

Comment: Only you know what can be there. What chars do you expect there? If they are optional, use `/^\*?Cats are:\*?\s*([\s\S]*)/` or `/^\**Cats are:\**\s*([\s\S]*)/`

Comment: Oh wow!! Super cool!! Thanks so much!! You're the best :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest

```
/^\**Cats are:\**\s*([\s\S]*)/
```

Here, any text is captured into Group 1 with `([\s\S]*)` and the asterisks are made optional with `*` quantifier meaning 0 or more repetitions.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wOslIm/2)

If the asterisks can appear 1 or 0 times, replace `*` with `?`:

```
/^\*?Cats are:\*?\s*([\s\S]*)/
    ^           ^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wOslIm/3).

Comment: Thank you so much! That cleared up all questions I had. Thank you for breaking things down!